# How to delete line separator for ContextMenu of UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, contextmenu, line-separator

I am implementing context menu for UICollectionView using the following function:

```
fun collectionView( _collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration?
```

All work well I had a menu which wants, but I don't know how to delete the line separator between the list of options. It's is possible?

This is a link to an image that describes the menu with a line separator I need to delete the line separator:

[image: Screenshot of Context Menu]

Comment: Since you can't really access the underlying `UIContextMenu`, and none of the menu objects you can create have an option to remove the separator, I would say that it's simply not possible.